# Difference between $\mathrm{ass}(M)$ and $\mathrm{supp}(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm reading through Lang's chapter about Noetherian modules and rings in Algebra. More specifically, subchapter about associated primes.

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ its module. If $\mathfrak p$ is an [associated prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime) of $M$, by definition, that means that there exists $x \in M$ such that $\mathrm{ann}(x) = \mathfrak p$.
Then, surely, $M_{\mathfrak p} \neq 0$ because $x/1 \neq 0$ in it.

This shows that $\mathrm{ass}(M) \subseteq \mathrm{supp}(M)$.
(You can read the definition of $\mathrm{supp}(M)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_of_a_module)).

I was searching for an example of $\mathrm{ass}(M) \neq \mathrm{supp}(M)$, but all my simple examples failed me. Can someone provide an example of this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple: take $A$ a noetherian domain. $\operatorname{Ass}A=\{0\}$ and $\operatorname{Supp}A=\operatorname{Spec}A$. They're different unless $A$ is a field.

*Note:* If $A$ is reduced, $\operatorname{Ass}A=\operatorname{Min}A$, which is different from $\operatorname{Spec}A$ if the Krull dimension of $A$ is positive.